Curcubits and biodegradable pots
I discovered the hard way just how much (established) curcubits don't like being transplanted.   Nevertheless, I'm wanting to get a jump on the growing season and have quite a few curcubits I want to try grow.
I see it is possible to get biodegradable pots (like https://primehort.co.nz/product/w-biopot/ - and i've seen things online to make my own from the likes of newspaper, toilet roll holders and egg cups.
Am I better to direct plant my curcubits, or - if I use a biodegradable pot and then bury the pot after the frosts are over, will this prevent the issues with transplanting and get my curcubits providing fruits sooner?

No plant like to be transplanted, but my experience you can do it on most of them (never tried on beans). My problem with them is just after transplanting (with seedling and small plants): snails kill many plants, so you should protect them.
Maybe you should improve how to transplant seedlings: keep as much of soil as possible: water before doing any operation: it helps keeping soil attached to roots (and to rest of soil). Uses spoon (and knife) (or better similar shaped tools) to remove seedlings, and keep wet the soil in new places for some days. Also such plants are often more sensitive to cold weather, so wait.
Direct plant is also feasible. I do (and wild board did it for me) regularly, without much problems, also because usually we have excess seeds. Just that rats like the seeds (but that is true also if you plan to transplant them).
For me the "sooner" is a problem: curbitaceae likes hot weather, so with direct planting you may lose weeks (seeds will not open if it is too cold), so look for good position in your garden and eventually add some protection. It is also a reason to transplant: you may do at different time, betting on climate, but without losing all seedlings if the weather was not ideal.
